# Как правильно перевести curl запрос на php Запрос?

Tags: php, парсер, http, curl

> curl -k -i -H "X-Request-Project: num1" -H "X-Request: Api-Request" -H
>   "Cookie: session=777888999" --data
>   '{"data":{"email":"","password":"","name":""},"list":["data"]}'
>   https://api.test.xyz/v1/user/data;

__

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = 'https://api.test.xyz/v1/user/data';
        $postData = json_encode([
            'data' => [
                "email" => "",
                "password" => ""
         "name" => ""],

            "list" => ["data"]
        ]);
        $sessionId = '777888999';
        //configure CURL
        $headers = json_encode(['POST'=>'/v1/user/data','Content-type' 
        => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Cookie' => "session=" . 
        $sessionId, 'Host' => 'api.test.xyz', 'X-Requested-Project' => 
        'num1', 'X-Requested-Type' => 'Api-Request']);
        $query = [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
//            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
//            CURLOPT_COOKIE => "session=$sessionId",
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
//            CURLOPT_SSL_ENABLE_NPN => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
//            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(''),
//            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
//            CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT => true,
        ];
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $query);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //convert JSON data back to PHP array
        $xz = json_decode($result);
```

Возвращает просто true
однако в терминале отображает то что нужно.

спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
```

По умолчанию, curl_exec() возвращает true в случае успеха или false в случае ошибки. Если установлена опция CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, то в случае успеха вернется результат обработки запроса.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php